# Diseño responsive al cambiar el tamaño del texto

Tags: java, android, android-studio, layout

He realizado una aplicación en java 
(android studio) para android. y la preparé para verse de la siguiente forma.

[image: como se debe ver]

El problema es al cambiar el tamaño de la letra en los ajustes de android.

[image: Ajustes de android]

Al cambiar a un tamaño L la aplicación se ve de la siguiente manera.

[image: Vista aplicación con tamaño L]

Pongo un trozo del código del layout XML. No me deja ponerlo entero por la limitación de carácteres:

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
           tools:context="com.rentabilidaddelalquiler.fragments.MainFragment">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="Importe de compra"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etImporteCompra"
                android:layout_width="113dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
                android:ems="6"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="7"
                android:text=""
                android:textSize="16sp"
                app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/textView1"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView19"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="€"
              app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@id/etImporteCompra"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/etImporteCompra" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
                android:text="Gastos de la compra"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView1"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView1" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etGastosCompra"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="6"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="7"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/textView3"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/etImporteCompra" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView27"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="€"
               app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@id/etGastosCompra"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/etGastosCompra" />
            <!-- android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit"  -->
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:background="#00FAFAFA"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_entrar_fragmento"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/etGastosCompra"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/ibHipoteca"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/ibHipoteca"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/etGastosCompra"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Se cortan los iconos de manitas y también parte de los textos de € y €/mes al hacer más grande el tamaño de la letra en android.
Cómo puedo solucionar este problema para que se vea bien independientemente del tamaño de la fuente de android? Muchas gracias

Comment: Agrega el layout al menos de lo que realizas, revisa por favor [ask].,saludos

Comment: Ya agregué el alyout. Gracias por el consejo. Entendí que no era importante para lo que estaba preguntando pero siempre es mejor pasarse de información.

Answer (score 0):

Me respondo yo mismo. Al final he añadido este texto al MainActivity y me ha funcionado

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    super.attachBaseContext(newBase);
    final Configuration override = new Configuration(newBase.getResources().getConfiguration());
    override.fontScale = 1.0f;
    applyOverrideConfiguration(override);
}
```